# Trying to find the equivalence class of an equivalence relation

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. For $a,\;b \in G$, let $a \sim b$ if $a^{-1}b \in H$

I've managed to show that this is an equivalence relation.

Now I have to show that

$$
[a]=aH=\left\{ ah\:|\:h \in H \right\}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$[a]=\{g\in G:a^{-1}g\in H\}=\{g\in G:a^{-1}g=h\text{ for some } h\in H\}=\{g\in G:g=ah\text{ for some } h\in H\}=\{g\in G:g\in aH\}=aH$$